# multi core and parallel processing

Tags: cpu

what is the difference between parallel processing and multi core processing

Answer (score 11):

Parallel and multi-core processing both refer to the same thing: the ability to execute code at the same time (in more than one core/CPU/machine.) So in this sense multi-core is just a means to do parallel processing.

On the other hand, concurrency (which is probably what you mean by parallel processing) refers to having multiple units of execution (threads or processes) that are interleaved. This can also happen in either in a single core CPU or in many cores/CPUs or even in many machines (clusters).

Summing up, multicore is a subset of parallel and concurrency can occur with or without parallelism. The field that studies this is [distributed systems](http://www.cs.vu.nl/~ast/books/ds1/) or [distributed computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing).

Comment: Actually Concurrency is when you have multiple threads of execution that are interleaved -- NOT parallelism.


"One of the misconceptions about concurrency is people often confuse concurrency and parallelism. Concurrency is a programming model that lets you express things that are independent, as independent executions and parallelism is about running two things at the same time. They are not the same idea and a lot of people confuse them, they think they are the same thing, but concurrency and parallelism are best thought of as a different idea." -- Rob Pike

Comment: Yes, I remember thinking about this when I was learning threading, back in the days where CPUs where single core and machines with multiple CPUs were rare, and thus the divergence between concurrency and parallelism more evident.

Comment: Yes, the two concepts have become blurred due to multi-core CPUs.

Comment: Could you update the link to distributed systems?

Answer (score 8):

[Parallel processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelization) just refers to a program running more than 1 part simultaneously, usually with the different parts communicating in some way. This might be on multiple cores, multiple threads on one core (which is really simulated parallel processing), multiple CPUs, or even multiple machines.

Multicore processing is usually a subset of parallel processing.

[Multicore processing means code working on more than one "core" of a single CPU chip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_(computing)). A core is like a little processor within a processor. So making code work for multicore processing will nearly always be talking about the parallelization aspect (though would also include removing any core specific assumptions, which you shouldn't normally have anyway).

As far as an algorithm design goes, if it is correct in a parallel processing point of view, it will be correct multicore.

However, if you need to optimise your code to get it to run as fast as possible "in parallel" then the differences between multicore, multi-cpu, multi-machine, or [vectorised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(computer_science)) will make a big difference.

Comment: Well said, and all of this is a subset of the 'Distributed systems' area of CS.

Comment: And I'd say the difference between multicore and multicpu is very thin, optimization wise (if we're talking about the same architecture)

Comment: True, but there can be differences, especially if you get down to cache size based optimisations (which you occasionally do, for example in intense crypto applications)

Answer (score 5):

Parallel processing can be done inside a single core with multiple threads.

Multi-Core processing means distributing those threads to make use of the multiple cores in a CPU.

Comment: Strictly speaking isn't the single core multithreaded application still doing things in a sequence on the hardware level?

Comment: yes, but the synchronization techniques used are the same techniques you would use if you had really many cores